# Lead Convert Issues

Tags: process-builder, lead-conversion

I have recently created a process builder that sets the lead type based on fields, date stamps when moved through the lead process stages, and sends email alerts when criteria is met.

My users cannot convert leads now. They get the error message that is is in a workflow. When I check the queue for specific leads, they are not there. Additionally, I do not have any time-based workflows set up that do not include `Cancel Workflow = FALSE`.

I already have the VF page that overrides the standard button to check the cancel workflow box in place. How do I resolve this? I am at a loss with troubleshooting at this point.

I have also deactivated the process builder on the lead object and still receive the error.

Comment: Do you have any time-based workflows on the lead object running in your org at all?

Answer (score 0):

A previous, deactivated version of the process builder had time-based actions. I did not realize these were tracked in flows versus workflow tracking. I found them (Setup > Process Automation > Flows), deleted them from the "Paused and Waiting Interviews" queue and am able to convert now.